# Build Apk file is not working same as debug APK file work in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have an **existing** project. I build an APK file a month ago for the first time. it was working the same as debugging APK file work in the emulator. But I have added **some new features** to my project and it works properly in the emulator. But when I  build an APK it is not updating anything(any features). it looks like the **same as before(previous build/version)**. Every feature appears and works properly in the emulator but after building APK file, not a single new feature is working on the mobile.

[image]

Comment: What command are you using for the release build?

Comment: @developius (`./gradlew clean`) then (`./gradlew assembleRelease`)